# Visual studio or resharper shortcut to close currently selected file in IDE

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a shortcut in VS 2005 or resharper to close the current file.  or "save and close" would be even better

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

Save and close would 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> followed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

Answer (score 11):

#### Visual Studio 2015 + Resharper

The question is a bit old. Just wanted to update it with the current solution.
As you can see below, you can also completely customize your shortcuts:

- just navigate to ***Tools > Options***

[image]

- on the left pane, go to ***Environment > Keyboard***

[image]

- now use the field ***Show commands containing*** to search for *file.close*
- select *File.Close* on the list
- click the field ***Press shortcuts keys***
- type your desired shortcut, for example, `<Ctrl> + W`
- finally, click ***Assign***

And you're good to go!

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> will save and close the current file.

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Keyboard

Find "Windos.CloseDocumentWindow"

And for me, need to set "Use new shortcut in" to "text editor" to override old ctrl+w without delete